# Angular JS - On click load controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I'm creating a small event app with angular for practicing. Currently i've created a application with Laravel 5.1 and returning some URL's with JSON. I load those URL's in my Factory for the events. Those events will be rendered with Angular. After they are rendered, a button with "Show info" will be placed and when you click at it, i want to call a function in the EventController so my $scope.event will receive the new data. My Controller has a function with $scope.getEvent(eventID); but i cant figure out how to run that function on click.

```
//Controller
app.controller('EventController', ['$scope', 'eventFactory', '$http', function ( $scope, eventFactory, $http )
{
    eventFactory.getEvents(1).then(function(response){
        $scope.events = response.events;
        $scope.eventPaginator = response.pagination;
    });

    $scope.getEvent = function(value){
        console.log('trigger');
        eventFactory.getEvent(value).then(function(response){
            $scope.event = response;
        });
    };

    $scope.loadPage = function(page){
        eventFactory.getEvents(page).then(function(response){
            $scope.events = response.events;
            $scope.eventPaginator = response.pagination;
        });
    };


}]);

//Directive
app.directive('event', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            loadEvent: '&',
        },
        templateUrl: '/assets/website/angular/views/event.html',
        link: function(scope, element){
            scope.loadEvent(function(){
                alert('Click')
            });
        },
    };
});

//Factory
app.factory('eventFactory', ['$http', function ( $http )
{
    return {
        getEvents: function (page)
        {
            return $http.get('/api/v1/events?page='+page)
                    .then(function ( response )
                    {
                        return response.data;
                    });
        },
        getEvent: function (id)
        {
            return $http.get('/api/v1/event/'+id)
                    .then(function ( response )
                    {
                        return response.data;
                    });
        }
    };
}]);


//View
<div class="event">
    <h2>[[data.event.title]] ID: [[data.event.id]]</h2>
    <div class="event-image">

    </div>
    <div ng-click="loadEvent(data.event.id)">Click voor [[data.event.id]]</div>
</div>




//HTML code for the Laravel View
<div class="col-md-9" ng-controller="EventController">
            <div class="btn btn-success" ng-click="getEvent(15)">Test</div>
            <div class="row">
                <h1 ng-bind="showEvent.event.title"></h1>
                {#<div class="col-md-12">#}
                    {#<h1 class="page-header">Page Heading <small>Secondary Text</small></h1>#}
                    {#<div ng-controller="BannerController">#}
                        {#<ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-auto-slide="3" rn-carousel-transition="slide" rn-carousel-duration="1000" class="image carousel">#}
                            {#<li ng-repeat="banner in banners">#}
                                {#<img ng-src="[[banner.image]]" alt="" class="img-responsive">#}
                            {#</li>#}
                        {#</ul>#}
                    {#</div>#}
                {#</div>#}
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="event in events">
                            <h1>Een event</h1>
                            <event data="event"></event>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h3>[[eventPaginator.total]]</h3>
                  <div class="pagination">
                        <div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:eventPaginator.total">
                            <button ng-click="loadPage(n+1)">[[n+1]]</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: how you wrote directive on the page? and where is directive html?

Comment: I've added my code from the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to call the parent controller function from the directive template with passing `id` parameter to it. For that you need to pass the method reference to the directive in by adding `load-event` attribute with `getEvent(id)` on the directive element.

Also you should remove the unwanted link which has wrong code in it.

```
//below code should remove from the directive.
scope.loadEvent(function(){
    alert('Click')
});
```

**Directive Template**

```
<event data="event" load-event="getEvent(id)"></event>
```

**Template**

```
<div ng-click="loadEvent({id: data.event.id})">Click voor [[data.event.id]]</div>
```

Comment: Yes that works fine! Thanks! Is there a bether way of doing this?

Comment: @DonnyvanV who you find bad in this way..? This is the only correct way of doing it.

Comment: Well its not a mather of finding it bad, but more a the logic that seems to be hard, i thought that the code i've written wasn't well enough like the controller and factory

Comment: @DonnyvanV which hard-coding part you are talking about?

Comment: My own code from the controller... Is my code fine or can it be done bether?

Comment: @DonnyvanV at a Glance I don't found any problem with your code..but if you are not really modifying or validating a data on `$http` success, then I would say that just do return `$http` promise there, like `return $http.get('/api/v1/events?page='+page);`

Comment: Thanks, i did it and it works fine :) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @DonnyvanV Only you need to do `response.data` in your `.then` function..anyways glad to help you. Thanks ;)